# Why does my accuracy not improve after training for 10 epochs?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've programmed an image classifier with PyTorch.
When I train the net with several parameters, it randomly either makes progress and learns or it doesn't learn anything. I ran the code several times and for the same parameters I have different results.

```
class Network(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Network, self).__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=5)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 12, kernel_size=5,)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(12, 24, kernel_size=3 )
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(24, 24, kernel_size=3 )
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(864, 300)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(300,2)


  def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)

    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)

    x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)

    x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
    #print(x.shape)
    x = x.reshape(-1, 864)

    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.fc2(x)
    return x

device= torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

data = CatDogs('train/',transforms.Compose([
                                                transforms.Resize(256),
                                                transforms.CenterCrop(256),
                                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                transforms.Normalize(
                                                    mean = [0.485,0.456,0.406],
                                                    std= [0.229,0.224,0.225])
                                                ]))
train_set, test_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [20000, 5000])

params = OrderedDict(
    batch_size = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]
    ,lr = [.005]
    ,shuffle = [True]
    ,pin_memory = [True]
    ,num_workers = [2]
    )

m = RunManager()

for run in RunBuilder.get_runs(params):
    network = Network()
    network = network.to(device)
    loader = DataLoader(train_set,
                        pin_memory=run.pin_memory,
                        batch_size=run.batch_size, 
                        shuffle=run.shuffle,
                        num_workers=run.num_workers)

    optimizer = optim.Adam(network.parameters(), lr=run.lr)
    network.train()
    m.begin_run(run, network, loader)
    for epoch in range(10):
      m.begin_epoch()
      for batch in loader: # Get Batch
        images, labels = batch
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        preds = network(images) # Pass Batch
        loss = F.cross_entropy(preds, labels) # Calculate Loss
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward() # Calculate Gradients
        optimizer.step() # Update Weights

        m.track_loss(loss, images)
        m.track_num_correct(preds, labels)
      m.end_epoch()
    m.end_run()
m.save('results_batchsize_3')
```

Example for my Output:

[image: Example for my Output]

The Class RunManager is tracking several stats like loss, accuracy, and time, but it doesn't intervene with the training.

As a result, the network returns positive results and the loss decreases, while sometimes the loss stays pretty much the same.

If you have any suggestion whats causing this, please let me know.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried a lower learning rate? This can happen for a variety of reasons, but a high learning rate is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try it out with a lower learning rate.

Comment: Thanks, it works better now.